# Data cannot be pushed in array declared in polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Following is the code to call function `loadRealTimeDataForLineGraph`, which is also a property of the component:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.loadRealTimeDataForLineGraph();        
}
```

and in the function body I am trying to push data to another property array with the component.

```
var data = { "key": "Spain", "values": [[1, 23], [2, 23], [3, 23], [4, 19]] };
this.dataForLineChartdataForLineChart.push(data);
```

And its throwing type error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

At this time `this.dataForLineChartdataForLineChart` is not defined. As says in error message, you may fire `this.loadRealTimeDataForLineGraph()` function after this property defined or loaded like;

```
static get observers() {return  [ 'checkData(dataForLineChartdataForLineChart)']
checkData(data) {
    if (data) {this.loadRealTimeDataForLineGraph();  }
}
```